# Dialyzer treats correct .plt file as invalid when it used for analysis

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, dialyzer

I've built .plt file for ejabberd and standard libraries with the following command:

```
$ dialyzer --build_plt --apps kernel stdlib erts mnesia eunit -o ./dialyzer/ejabberd.plt /path/to/ejabberd/repository/ebin/*.beam
```

The manual check of generated file states that this file is valid:

```
$ dialyzer --check_plt dialyzer/ejabberd.plt 
  Checking whether the PLT /home/citxx/.dialyzer_plt is up-to-date... yes
done (passed successfully)
```

But when I try to check my source code using this .plt file the following error occurs:

```
$ dialyzer --plts dialyzer/ejabberd.plt ebin/*.beam
  Checking whether the PLT dialyzer/ejabberd.plt is up-to-date...
dialyzer: The file: dialyzer/ejabberd.plt is not a valid PLT file
Use the options:
   --build_plt   to build a new PLT; or
   --add_to_plt  to add to an existing PLT

For example, use a command like the following:
   dialyzer --build_plt --apps erts kernel stdlib mnesia
Note that building a PLT such as the above may take 20 mins or so

If you later need information about other applications, say crypto,
you can extend the PLT by the command:
  dialyzer --add_to_plt --apps crypto
For applications that are not in Erlang/OTP use an absolute file name.
```

The same happens if standard applications aren't included in plt file.

**What can be the reason of such behavior?**

UPD. I'm using ejabberd 14.05 and erlang OTP 17.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- The `-o` option doesn't make Dialyzer write the PLT to the given file, but the *analysis results*.  Look at the file, and you'll see it is a text file.  The option you want is `--output_plt`.
- `--check_plt` doesn't take a PLT file name.  Note that it says that `/home/citxx/.dialyzer_plt` is valid, not the file you referenced.  You need to combine it with a `--plt` or `--plts` argument, like this:

  ```
  dialyzer --check_plt --plts dialyzer/ejabberd.plt
  ```

Comment: The Dialyzer options are indeed confusing sometimes :)